# Why do we exclude jpg,css file in jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I am just wondering why do we exclude photos and css files in jmeter script because if i think from end user prospective,images takes more time to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

css/jpg/js files are all embedded static resources in the HTML response you get.

so instead of sending a recorded request, you can select the below option in the HTTP sampler. JMeter will take care of downloading these files for you just like a real browser.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The only content to be excluded from test script is "external" content, i.e. any third-party banners, pictures, maps, analytics, etc. content needs to be filtered out.

JMeter test needs to be as much realistic as possible to correctly simulate user activity. So:

1. Images, scripts, styles, etc. do not need to be excluded from JMeter test
2. The best way to handle them is as Vinoth S suggests using "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" functionality (and it is also better to use concurrent pool of 2-4 threads for it). The most optimal way of configuring it is via [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) config element so the change could be applied to all HTTP Request Samplers.
3. It is also good to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) from "reality" perspective as real browsers download all this stuff like images, scripts and styles, but they do it only once, on subsequent requests the content is being returned from browser's cache and the actual request to the server is not being made.

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743654-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for other recommendations on how to make your test more realistic.